# different types of rear shock suspension and their uses?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, suspension, full-suspension

explain me about the rear suspension of mountain bike.

Comment: This question as it is is far to broad to give a concise answer. Think about explicit questions and ask separately.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very rough answer to your very generic and open ended question:

A rear suspension (or shock), together with the front suspension (fork), allows the bike to handle more terrain roughness. This gives you:

- safety
- traction
- ability to go faster

The main two types of rear suspensions are:

- air sprung
- coil

Generally air suspensions are lighter and better for XC, all mountain, enduro. Coil shocks are heavier, more linear and better for downhill. See [What's the difference between All-Mountain, Cross Country, Freeride, Downhill bikes?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16814/whats-the-difference-between-all-mountain-cross-country-freeride-downhill-bi/16822#16822) for a reference on mountain bike types.